# What modelling approaches are used to predict the aurora?

Tags: models, auroras

Are there any resources (books/links) that discuss the mathematical tools and methods used to forecast the aurora borealis activity in a particular location?

I see many websites that claim to predict aurora, but are there any open source code that lets you have an idea of the models?

Comment: Have a read of [NOAA's Space Weather Prediction](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/) pages, especially the bit about [models](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/models). Maybe you will have more specific questions after reading a bit more about it.

Comment: Thanks, but um, where is the forecasting formula? Or is it not public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One model is the [OVATION auroral precipitation model](http://sd-www.jhuapl.edu/Aurora/ovation/).**

OVATION [stands for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) Oval  Variation,  Assessment,  Tracking,  Intensity, and  Online  Nowcasting.

The [NOAA Space Weather Prediction Center](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/) uses the OVATION Prime model for their 30-minute aurora forecast. They use a modified version of the model for their [3-day forecast](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/aurora-3-day-forecast). It was devised by Newell et al. (2010) at Johns Hopkins University.

You can read all about it in Machol et al. (2013). [The paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2011SW000746/full) is open access and contains several equations and a description of the method. They explain:

> The OVATION Prime model is derived from electron and proton
>   flux measurements from the SSJ4 detectors on the [DMSP satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Meteorological_Satellite_Program).

SSJ4 sensors, according to [one source](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Personal/Thesis/node28.html):

> [...consist] of an array of four cylindrical, curved plate, electrostatic analyzers configured into two pairs; one pair each to measure electrons and ions. Each pair covers the energy range from 30 eV to 30 keV in 20 channels spaced at equal intervals in energy on a logarithmic scale.

#### References

Machol, J. L., J. C. Green, R. J. Redmon, R. A. Viereck, and P. T. Newell (2012), Evaluation of OVATION Prime as a forecast model for visible aurorae, Space Weather, 10, S03005, [doi:10.1029/2011SW000746](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2011SW000746/full).

Newell, P. T., T. Sotirelis, and S. Wing (2010a), Seasonal variations in diffuse, monoenergetic, and broadband aurora, J. Geophys. Res., 115, A03216, [doi:10.1029/2009JA014805](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2009JA014805/full).